# WordPress: All posts are rendering instead of rendering only assigned taxonomy posts on taxonomy page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a `products` post type and it has a various categories. Currently there are around fifty plus posts assigned to different categories. Note: I am using a **custom taxonomy** called `product_categories`.

Scenario:

1. I have a category named `food-products` and it has a sub categories as `chocolates, dairy, grocery`.
2. Now when user goes to the category page eg `site.com/product-category/food-products` at that time **all other categories posts are also displaying** *but* **when i click on the sub category tabbing menu at that time it displays the correct assigned sub category posts**

***So, my question is how can the only the respected category of subcategory posts will be displayed on page load ?***

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
$count =0; ?>        
<div class="row portfolio-container">
<?php if ( $loop ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
  $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'thumbnail_size' );
  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_categories' );
  if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
    $links = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term )  { $links[] = $term->name; }
      $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links); 
      $tax = join( " ", $links );     
  else :  
    $tax = '';  
  endif; ?>      
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item <?php echo strtolower($tax); ?>">
    <div class="portfolio-wrap">
      <img src="<?php echo $url;?>" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      <div class="portfolio-info">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
        <div class="portfolio-links">
          <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="App 1" class="link-preview" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;?>
  <?php wp_reset_query();?>
  <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  var portfolioIsotope = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
  });
  $('#portfolio-flters li').on( 'click', function() {
    $("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
    $(this).addClass('filter-active');
    portfolioIsotope.isotope({ filter: $(this).data('filter') });
  });
});
```

Here is my working [demo video](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/252075?key=8a803b0a4133621b300cdfdf610b373e) for review.

Comment: I'm not clear what exactly the problem is... do you want it to show products from just one category on page load? IThat is to do with the filter, not the php. Or do you mean that it is showing posts that are not in the categories you want?

Comment: I have a category named `food-products` and it  has a sub categories as `chocolates`, `dairy`, `grocery`. Now when user goes to the category page eg `site.com/product-category/food-products` at that time all other categories posts are also displaying but when i click on the sub category tabbing menu at that time it displays the correct assigned sub category posts.... So, my question is how can the only the respected category of subcategory posts will be displayed on page load ?

Comment: I understand now, thanks. It might be a good idea to edit your question to include this extra information so that it might help to other people with similar problems  I've posted an answer below, hope that helps!

Comment: Okay sir, let me update my question and let i try your solution.

Comment: Not sir... I'm female :) Let me know how you get on with the answer.

Comment: Answer updated!

Comment: Phew...!!! You are a magician of the WordPress... !!! Once again thank you so so much for your time and constant support.

Comment: "*a magician of the WordPress*"...I like that! Maybe I'll make that my screen name :D Glad to help, I don't mind spending time with someone like you who genuinely wants to learn & to help others here too. And now you have more knowledge to help out other users :)  "Pay it forward" and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WP_Query` is returning all products, so that is why they are all getting shown on page load. You need to change the query so it only gets the ones in the category/categories you want.

You want to get products in a certain category, e.g. `food-products` and all it's sub categories, (e.g. `chocolates`).

To do this, you can change your WP_Query to specify the category to use like this :

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
               array('post_type' => 'product', 
                     'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                      array( 'category_name' => 'food-products' ) // <-- THIS!! Also note that it is in an array
               ));
```

This tells WP_Query to get **all** `product` posts that belong to the `food-products` category, so it will return any products with the `food-products` category *as well as* any products in any of the child categories, e.g. `chocolates`

WP_Query has a number of different ways you can query by category... take a look at the [category section of the WP_Query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters) for more information.

---

**UPDATE: Custom Taxonomies**

You can do the same thing for custom taxonomies, but you need to use `tax_query`  in the arguments instead of `category_name`. Your WP_Query should be something like this:

```
// you don't need to create a variable for the args, if just makes it clearer in the example
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(                            // note the nested arrays
              'taxonomy' => 'product_categories',  // this is the name of your custom taxonomy
              'field' => 'slug',          // you can search by slug, name, term_id or term_taxonomy_id
              'terms' => 'food-products'  // the taxonomy slug to search for
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

You might need to change the values for `taxonomy` and `term` to match your custom taxonomy. I've also assumed you are searching by slug, but you can search by name or id either.

There is an **`include_children`** parameter for the tax_query that you use to say whether or not to include children (e.g. `chocolates`) in the results, but this defaults to `true` so you only need to use it if you *don't* want to include children.

Here's the [taxonomy section of the WP_Query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) for more information.

---

**UPDATE 2: Getting the products for the current category**

You say in the comments that you have one template for all of the terms `taxonomy-product_categories.php`, each category shows in its own page using this template but you only want to show the products with the current term.

What you need to do is use just the current term in the `WP_Query`, not all of them. You should be able to use `get_queried_object()` to get the current term and use it in your `tax_query` instead of hard coding the specific terms.

```
// get the term of the current page
// We can then use $currentterm->slug in tax_query to dynamically search for this term instead of hard coding a specific term
$currentterm = get_queried_object();

$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(                            // note the nested arrays
              'taxonomy' => 'product_categories',  // this is the name of your custom taxonomy
              'field' => 'slug',          // you can search by slug, name, term_id or term_taxonomy_id
              'terms' => $currentterm->slug  // search for the slug of the current term
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

So what this should do is: if you are on e.g. `site.com/product-category/food-products`, it will get the current term which is `food-products` and then only search for products with that category.
When you go to e.g. `site.com/product-category/home-decor`, it will dynamically pick up the new term as `home-decor` and use it in the query.

Comment: Are you using the standard categories or is it a custom taxonomy? They need different arguments in WP_Query

Comment: I'm using custom taxonomy. `product_categories` this is the name of my custom taxonomy and cpt is `product`

Comment: Your comment gives me a way to change the query parameters, but i still did not understand the reason that firstly it loads all the posts and then after loading is completes it display those respected categories posts.

Comment: I have applied the terms as `'terms' => array('festive-products', 'home-decor', 'food-products')` but it works for only first `festive-products` term parameter. For rest of two it is not working and renders all the posts. Any clues ?

Comment: Do you mean you are still getting all posts even though they are not in `food-products`, `festive-products or `home-decor`, or is it that all the products in your required are displayed on page load but you would like them to show just one category on page load?

Comment: It works perfectly for `festive-products` argument, but not for `home-decor` and `food-products`.

Comment: `'terms' => array('festive-products', 'home-decor', 'food-products')` looks right. Are they all slugs? Maybe try with `'field' => 'term_id'` and the ids in the array for `terms`. Or you could try this for tax_array: `'tax_query' => array( 'relation' => 'OR', array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_categories', 'field'  => 'slug', 'terms'  => 'festive-products' ), array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_categories', 'field'  => 'slug', 'terms' => 'home-decor' ), array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_categories', 'field'  => 'slug', 'terms'  => 'food-products' ) )` (or using ids) It should be the same but worth a try :)

Comment: Other things to check: Does it work if you try with only the `home-decor` or `'festive-products'` term in the WP_Query? Do the all the posts have the post type `product`? Are all these terms in the `product_categories` taxonomy? Do they all have products or are the products only in their children? I'm sure they all are but I'm not sure what else to try! Also, you want products from all 3 of these terms on the same page, is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216552/discussion-between-aananddham-and-fluffykitten).